# how to count duplicate Name in java

Tags: java, string

Suppose you have a string as input which has names separated by the underscore character. Write a program that outputs the same string after removing any duplicate names in it (retain first occurrence when multiple occurrences are present), and adds the number of times the name occurs, immediately after the name. For example, `Tom_Dick_Harry_Joe_Dick_Chris` becomes `Tom1_Dick2_Harry1_Joe1_Chris1`.

Comment: http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/09/how-to-find-duplicate-words-in-a-string-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

I will provide no code but the following might help :

- Split the array with '_'
- Maintain a `Map<String,Integer> occurrences` for counting the occurrences of each name and a `List<String> apparitionOrder`
- For each word of the array :

  - if the word is in occurrences, increment the value associated to the key
  - else, put this name in the map associated with 0 and append it to apparitionOrder
- Instantiate a new array of the size of apparitionOrder
- Fill the new array accordingly to apparitionOrder and occurrences